# Select next element of a given type after specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select an element based on whether another element has a given ID containing certain text. The problem is that there are multiple elements with this same class name on the page and I only want to select the ones that have the element with this ID directly above them. Is this possible? I tried:

```
if ($(".element[id*='XYZ']").length > 0){ 

    $(".element").nextAll('.elementoselect').text('Change the text');

 }
```

My first instinct was to do it based on them being within the same DIV but the problems is that the DIVs are given classes when the page loads and they are generic, so this is the only other way I could think of.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this now.

Answer (score 1):

Use chaining with the selector

```
$(".element[id*='XYZ']").nextAll('.elementoselect').text('Change the text');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use selector chaining , your oissue could be solved

```
$(".element[id*='XYZ']").nextAll('.elementoselect').text('Ch‌​ange the text')
```

Comment: I've tried but it's not working. Would this work if there are elements inbetween or does nextALL find the next element with that ID regardless of what's inbetween them?

Comment: Post your html structure

Comment: <div class="Elementcontainer">
   <div class="Elementdiv">
   
    <p class="Element"></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="stu">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("xyz").value = 'XXX' + new Date().getTime();
    </script>
 
    <p class="EXLResultAvailability">
    <em class="Elementtochange">Texttochange</em>
    </p>

 
  </div>

Comment: Can't seem to format it properly. 'Element' is the one I'm selecting and 'Elementtochange' is the one i'm doing the .nextAll on.